# Select element within shadow root

Tags: html, jquery, css, shadow-dom

I want to change a property in element hidden within shadow root. Due to the nature of a project I can't refer to document in JS directly, I can only use custom class (which doesn't work with shadow root) or jQuery, but I don't know how to write a path to the element.

The element does not have "part" so I can't use it in selector.

What I've already tried - I selected last element above shadow and referenced its shadowRoot, then I tried to find encapsulated element by its id. I was testing it in devtool, so far with no success.

```
$("#root_ptcschartline-7-bounding-box".shadowRoot).find("#chart-line")
  .css('padding','100px');
```

html snippet:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

No need for jQuery selectors since IE9 was released... in 2011

`[element].querySelector( selector )` uses the same notation

[image]

- `let div = document.querySelector("#root_ptcschartline-7-bounding-box");`
  gets you the `<div>`
- `let chartLine = div.querySelector("ptcs-chart-line");`
  gets you the `<ptcs-chart-line>` element
- `let shadow = chartline.shadowRoot;`
  gets you the shadowRoot reference
- `let layout = shadow.querySelector("#chart-layout")`
  gets you the `<ptcs-chart-layout>` element

**all combined**

Note! This will only work for `#shadow-root (open)` Not for `#shadow-root (closed)`

```
let layout = document
               .querySelector("#root_ptcschartline-7-bounding-box ptcs-chart-line")
               .shadowRoot
                   .querySelector("#chart-layout");

layout.style.padding = "100px";
```

[Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) docs on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

As I've mention I cannot use "document".

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNOiP.png)

Although this seems to do the trick:

```
$('#chart-layout', $('#root_ptcschartline-7-bounding-box ptcs-chart-line')[0].shadowRoot).css('padding');
```