# How to get this field to autofill - Kotak securities Neo login page nameless idless field

Tags: javascript, firefox, autofill, userscripts

In this website https://neo.kotaksecurities.com/Login

How do I get the mobile number field to autofill? The input field neither has a name nor an id. The firefox autofill extension fails to detect the input field. Can I write a userscript and use it in TamperMonkey? How do I access the nameless and IDless field?
[image]

How do I  populate it via a userscript? I think it is using dart to generate the webpage.

Here's the relevant source code

```
<body flt-renderer="html (requested explicitly)" flt-build-mode="release" style="position: fixed; inset: 0px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; none; touch-action: none; font: 14px sans-serif; color: red;" spellcheck="false">
   <!--Google Tag Manager (noscript)--> 
   <noscript></noscript>
   <!--End Google Tag Manager (noscript)-->
   <script></script>
   <script></script>
   <script></script>
   <script defer="" crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://lapi.kotaksecurities.com/eum/eum.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@2.12.313/build/pdf.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script> event
   <flt-glass-pane style="position: absolute; inset: 8px; cursor: default;">
      event
      #shadow-root (open)
      <style> </style>
      <fit-semantics-placeholder role="button" aria-live="polite" tabindex="e" aria-label="Enable accessibility"
         style="position: absolute; left: -1px; top: 1px; width: 1px; height: 1px;">
      </flt-semantics-placeholder> event
      <flt-scene-host style="pointer-events: none;">
      </fit-scene-host> 
      <flt-semantics-host style="position: absolute; transform-origin: 0px 0px 8px; transform: scale(1.25);">
      </flt-semantics- host>
      <flt-ruler-host style="position: fixed; visibility: hidden; overflow: hidden; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 0px; height:
         8px;">
      </fit-ruler-host>
      <form novalidate="" method="post" action="#" style="white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; padding: 0px; -px; transform-origin: 0px 0px 8px; caret-color: transparent;"> event
         <input class="submitBtn" style="white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; padding: 0px; 8px; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; caret-color: transparent;" type="submit">
         <input class="fit-text-editing" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" style="white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; position: abso. height: 25px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 915.25, 238.5);"> event
      </form>
   </flt-glass-pane>
</body>
```

The input field I'm interested in is the second input in the form:

```
<input class="fit-text-editing" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="on" style="white-space: pre-wrap; align-content: center; position: abso. height: 25px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 915.25, 238.5);"> event
```

For clarity the dev-tools screenshot is also posted
[image]

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: it's inside a shadow-root element. You can access it via javascript using something like: `const el = document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane')` and then `const mobInput = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('form input+input')`

Comment: as seen on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66384836/select-element-within-shadow-root

Comment: I'm really amazed. People are more interested in closing questions and trolling questions rather than answering the question! SO isnt the same it used to be years ago. 
I'm no javascript expert to provide debugging information. I just wanted a simple userscript to work.
I still dont fully understand how `querySelector('form input+input')` works. But it does. Thanks to GrafiCode!!!

Comment: @Mavin We are interested in not getting StackOverflow flooded with useless / non-helpful questions, so it remains the useful resource it is to us. If you had read the links provided above ([ask] and [tour]), you would know _why_ this question is not useful in its current state: In a year, the website hosted at the URL you are linking will have changed, so at that point, noone will be able to understand your actual problem here, nor understand how the answer below solved it. Thus, your question was correctly closed as "needs debugging details". [Edit] those in and it can be reopened.

Comment: Source code posted as requested, though dev tools does not allow one to copy... Go figure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works. It works only on the first click though, I'm not sure why. If it can display a dropdown autofill entry selection list that would be the ultimate thing I guess, but it works for now. Thanks [@GrafiCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334486/graficode) for the tip! Much appreciated!!

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name            Kotak Neo Autofill Mobile nameless idless input field
// @namespace
// @version         1
// @license         MIT http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
// @include https://neo.kotaksecurities.com/Login
// @grant GM_setValue
// @grant GM_getValue
// @grant GM_setClipboard
// @grant unsafeWindow
// @grant window.close
// @grant window.focus
// @run-at document-idle


// ==/UserScript==



(function() {
    function onClick(evt) {
            const el = document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane')
            const mobInput = el.shadowRoot.querySelector('form input+input')
            mobInput.value = +919012345678
            mobInput.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keyup", {
               "key": "9",
               "keyCode": 57,
               "which": 57,
               "code": "Digit9",
               "location": 0,
               "altKey": false,
               "ctrlKey": false,
               "metaKey": false,
               "shiftKey": false,
               "repeat": false
           }));

    }
    document.addEventListener('click', onClick);
}) ();
```